# Symfony 6 Difficulties to debug using Xdebug in PhpStorm

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpstorm, xdebug, symfony6

to solve a problem calling Doctrine flush() I'm trying to debug with xdebug (I'm totally new to this). I think I configured xdebug well but I am not sure to use it properly.

I put a breakpoint on Doctrine call to flush(), I switch on xdebug helper browser, then I run xdebug configuration. Debugger stops quickly on `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection`, in `getEnv()` method where `unset($this->resolving[$envName]);` is performed, whereas no exception is raised when I launch my app.

So my first question is: does this mean there is a bug during this call to `unset()` or is the debugger simply inspect each step?

Another question is why can't I step out to my breakpoint ? I tried to but it seems to act like step into ?

Thank you for any help / information. I may be no clear enough, tell me if you need more context.

Alex

Comment: `then I run xdebug configuration` - please clarify what it means. After switching Xdebug Helper on, the only thing you need to do is to refresh the page that eventually executes the file containing the breakpoint. It's usually helpful to look at the [Xdebug remote log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs) to understand what Xdebug is doing and why

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your help. Actually, I start debugging clicking on "Run" in phpstorm debug bar after switching Xdebug Helper on. But code is analyzed without I need to refresh the page. Actually I'm now thinking I am possibly mixing two ways of using xdebug (running it from phpstorm or using Xdebug Helper)... And xdebug stops at two different points depending on how I use it.

Comment: So, what if you don't start anything from PhpStorm and rely solely on Xdebug Helper - does Xdebug stop where you expect it to?

Comment: The initial bug has been fixer (a bug in one of my company's bundles). I didn't have much time to investigate about xdebug. Thanks anyway for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Initial bug due to a proprietary bundle. This has been corrected without using xdebug.